# Android Studio attributes missing in Layout Preview and XML

Tags: android-studio, attributes, designer

I'm using Android Studio to create an app. However when I try to change a View/Layout, Android Studio does not show the proper attributes anymore:

[image: Android-Studio, missing attributes]

I can still "add" attributes, when I manually do so inside the XML. However, I would normally use the suggestions as help, as I am pretty new to using Android Studio and Android programming in general. The suggestions shown when I try to manually set the attributes in the XML are the same as the ones shown in the designer.

I already did the whole "Ivalidate Caches/Restart"-Thing, but it didn't change and I really don't know where to start here.

I can't say for sure, but I believe this behaviour started with the last or second to last update of Android Studio.

```
Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 29, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

### Edit

As I just noticed, setting attribute values manually in the XML file results in the following warning:

[image: Unknown attribute warning]

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page of the screen, you should be able to switch between Design and Text cards. Check this one. Both of those views look similar but attributes are available only at the design card.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but I believe you overlooked something. As you can see by the palette window (left) and Attributes window (right) of the first picture, I actually am in design mode. Seems like AndroidStudio was just bugging around. For the time being, I just stuck to doing everything via text mode, but the bug disappeared just as quick as it appeared. So while my problem was "solved", i dont really know how. It just happened.

Comment: Sorry, I did 'upsi' here with that:)